# How do I reference a cell with notes still attached in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm simply looking for how to link one cell's data with the notes still attached into another cell and/or sheet.

With my code I cant't seem to figure out how to reference a single cell from another sheet with the notes still attached. This is the best code I have about it. I get error that range is not found. I'm using =copyNote(Ref!B59)

```
function copyNote(cell) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getNote();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

It's not possible to use a custom function to make that a cell shows the referenced cell value and note. Instead use function to copy the cell.

## Explanation

Custom functions can only return values, they can't modify cell attributes like cell notes.

### References in custom functions

Instead of `Ref!B59` use `"Ref!59"` or `cell("address",Ref!B59)`. The final formula will be  `=copyNote("Ref!B59")` or `=copyNote(cell("address",Ref!B59))`

The above will return the value of the note from Ref!B59.

A more elaborated approach is to use getFormula() and regular expressions to extract the reference from the formula.

### Workarounds

#### Using a script to copy a cells

The following function will copy a fixed cell to another fixed cell including. This will include notes.

```
function copyCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var origin = ss.getRange('A1');
  var destination = ss.getRange('F1');
  origin.copyTo(destination);
}
```

#### Using custom functions

In case that a custom function should be used, to get the value and the note from a cell reference, some changes should be done to the function. The following code returns a 1X2 array, the first resulting cell will contain the referred cell value and the second resulting cell the referred cell note:

```
function copyValueNote(cell) {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell);  
  return [['Value: ' + rng.getValue(),'Note: ' + rng.getNote()]];
}
```

Comment: I used =copyNote(cell("address",Ref!B59)). It returns to the cell the note attached successfully, but without referencing what was in the cell. What I was looking for was a way to reference a cell range with data and notes still attached. Like having a master list that I can reference, but I want the notes to still transfer over retroactively. Hope that makes sense. I feel like setNote() is needed, I keep trying to add in it but I couldn't seem to make it work.

Comment: @Frank: Edited my answer.

Comment: That didnt work

Comment: Did you get an error message?

Comment: Not an error. Just that I meant it's not working the way I was intending to. With yours above, in one cell it displays "Value: " and in the adjacent cell to the right it displays "Note: " with the contents of each. It doesn't create a note. It seems like it just copy's a cell and splits the note and the value.

Comment: I understand that rather than "as intended" you mean "as expected".

Comment: I made some changes to the answer to make it clearer.